# Ronin M vs. Helix Jr

Tags: stabilisation, gear

Has anybody used the new DJI Ronin-M and compared it to the Letus Helix Jr.?
I'm considering a gimbal purchase for my DSLR videography and haven't seen anything that tells me why the Helix is twice the price of the Ronin-M.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For half the price and DSLRs only, the Ronin M probably makes more sense. The Helix Jr. makes sense for more. It can hold up to 12 lb of stuff vs the M's 8 lb (which is kind of crazy, considering that it's even lighter), and the fact that it's naturally at heart-ish level as opposed to belt level means a lot for good framing and the ability to hold it at a good frame for an extended period of time. You can get it to eye level for more easily than the Ronin, even in Upright mode (or whatever it's called), because it flips the camera upside down. (They both have briefcase mode for very low shots.)

If you want a second person with total control, the Ronin is absolutely the way to go. But if you're a one-man band and can afford the premium, the Helix is probably the better option.

Source: I have demoed both.